# When selecting option in 2nd "select" section, that specific option does not hide in the first "select" section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to replicate issue:** If I select an option in the first "select", that specific option hides in the 2nd "select". However next, if I select an option in the 2nd "select", the newly selected option does not hide in the 1st "select"

How do I get this to happen? Anytime I select something, it should hide itself in the other "select" sections

```js
$(function() {
  var sec = $('.security');
  sec.change(function() {
    console.log("security change!");
    let currentSelect = sec.find('option:selected').val();
    $('.security option').each(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      if (self.val() === currentSelect) {
        self.hide();
      } else {
        self.show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
  <label for="security-question-1"><span class="trn">Security Question</span> 1 *</label>
  <select class="form-control security" id="security-question-1">
    <option class="trn" disabled selected value>select a question</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q1">What is the name of your first school?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q2">What is your favorite movie?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q3"> What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q4">What street did you grow up on?</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
  <label for="security-question-2"><span class="trn">Security Question</span> 2 *</label>
  <select class="form-control security" id="security-question-2">
    <option class="trn" disabled selected value>select a question</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q1">What is the name of your first school?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q2">What is your favorite movie?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q3"> What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q4">What street did you grow up on?</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, check out my comment as well

```js
$(function () {
      var sec = $('.security');
      sec.change(function () {
        let currentSelect=$(this).find('option:selected').val(); // Your code use sec.find() which is wrong since it picks the first selected option of first select.
        $('.security option').show();
        $('.security option[value="' + currentSelect + '"]').hide(); // This is shorter code.
      }).change();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
  <label for="security-question-1"><span class="trn">Security Question</span> 1 *</label>
  <select class="form-control security" id="security-question-1">
    <option class="trn" disabled selected value>select a question</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q1">What is the name of your first school?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q2">What is your favorite movie?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q3"> What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
    <option class="trn" value="q4">What street did you grow up on?</option>
  </select>
</div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="security-question-2"><span class="trn">Security Question</span> 2 *</label>
    <select class="form-control security" id="security-question-2">
      <option class="trn" disabled selected value>select a question</option>
      <option class="trn" value="q1">What is the name of your first school?</option>
      <option class="trn" value="q2">What is your favorite movie?</option>
      <option class="trn" value="q3"> What is your mother's maiden name?</option>
      <option class="trn" value="q4">What street did you grow up on?</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want to reopen this quickly, how do I handle this scenario if there are THREE select sections? I am noticing the third select section shows the already selected option